# Начал мерехтеть экран мак 2015 15 radeon r9 2.5 intel

Tags: mac

Пару дней назад заметил мигание определенной части  экрана мака при скролле.

Например скролишь вниз и могут появится а могут и не появится горизонтальные полосы. Воспроизводилось только при скролле и не часто. где то 1 раз в минуту.

Я обновил ос до 10.14.04 перезагрузил мак проблема исчезла. Уже 2 дня мигания нет.

Гонял видеокарту, проц на Blender Benchmark. Открывал закрывал мак, мерцание не повторилось.

Эта проблема могла быть вызвана только ос? Не знаю что делать с мак.

Comment: Вас это так беспокоит? :)

Comment: Да) мак на гарантии до сентября. Если это аппаратная проблема хочу научится воспроизводить ее что бы произвести гарантийный ремонт.

Comment: вот тут написано, что у людей такие проблемы начались на версии 10.13.4 https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8353748

Comment: возможно проблемы в разводке видеопамяти и им приходится снижать частоту

Comment: Я так понимаю что это скорее всего не аппаратная проблема. Иначе бы видеокарты не смогли пройти тесты. ...